# Mouse scroll Lock by code?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, xslt, scroll

The problem I have is that when I click on any button and then refresh the scroll on my mouse stops working for that page. I have to manually go to the scroll bar on the right and scroll to "*unlock*" my mouse scroll so that I can scroll using my mouse scroll again or if I tab down forcing the page to scroll will also "*Unlock*" the mouse scroll. Refreshing the page again will "*Unlock*" the mouse scroll, but sometimes every 3rd or 4th refresh will "*lock*" the mouse scroll. What **does not** "*Unlock*" the mouse scroll is if I do something on the page that does not require it to scroll or refresh. Everything still works the way it is suppose to be, and I can go to other pages and use my mouse scroll.

I have narrowed down to two possibility, if I am wrong and there could be another reason please say so.
First is my button, I create them two ways:

```
 <input type="button" id="saveButton" onclick="onSave(event)" value="Save" 
    class="k-button" style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:5px"/>

 <button id="submitButton" onclick="submitTheForm()" >Submit</button>
```

Note that `onSave`, `submitTheForm` is empty, I commented out everything and it it still "*locks*" the page. Is there anything wrong here?

Second is the way my form is created. I download my XML from my server. I then create a XSLTProcessor and use it's method `transformToFragment` to create a `DOM DocumentFragment node` [Link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations). I then save the `DOM DocumentFragment node` into `document.htmlForm` to be use later.

```
 xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
 xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(document.xmlFormStylesheet);
 var htmlFormsFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(document.xmlFormData, 
 document);
 var formsList = $(htmlFormsFragment).children("form_1")[0];           
 document.htmlForm = formsList;
```

When ever the user wants to add a new form to the page they click a button that clone the saved form and append to a the `<div id="formContainer">` containing all the forms

```
function createNewForm(formId) {
// clone the form, add id, and attach new title
var newForm = $(document.htmlForm).clone(true, true)[0];
// pull the content if 
if (formId == null) {
   ...default intialization
}
$(newForm).attr("id", formId);

// any element in the form with an id will be prefixed
...
// change the "for" attribute for all the labels
....
//mask the input field for the premise cloned
....
//apply kendoUi       
//find each select and date element in the premise part of the form and make it into a kendo widget
....
// trigger the copy event and append to the document
$("#formContainer").append(newForm);

$(document).trigger("cloneform", newForm);

return newForm;
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This behavior is happening only in Google Chrome. Also when I refresh on the other browser I am the same spot that where I refreshed. While in Google chrome it take me back to the top of the page.